# How to Calculate the number of bytes in a sector of the hard disk

Tags: operating-system, virtual-memory

I want to know how to calculate the no of bytes in a sector of the hard disk

Answer (score 1):

For Linux you can use below command:

```
# cat /sys/block/sda/queue/hw_sector_size
512
```

Where /dev/sda is your hard disk device name.

For Windows you can use IOCTL: IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winioctl/ni-winioctl-ioctl_disk_get_drive_geometry

Sample code for Windows:

```
{
    DISK_GEOMETRY diskGeometry;
    GET_LENGTH_INFORMATION lengthInfo;
    DWORD bytesReturned;
    BOOL ret;

    ret = DeviceIoControl( 
                          hDevice, // file handle to the physical device
                          IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY, 
                          NULL,
                          0,
                          &diskGeometry,
                          sizeof(DISK_GEOMETRY),
                          &bytesReturned,
                          NULL);
    if (TRUE != ret) {
       // Log error and exit
    }

    bytesPerSector = diskGeometry.BytesPerSector;
}
```

Comment: Thank you..This answer is so helpful